# post_row_actions for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

I'm using [this](http://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/duplicate-post.html) code to have a duplicate post function in WordPress Admin. However, when I add the filter for a custom post type, like this:

```
add_filter( 'directory_row_actions', 'rd_duplicate_post_link', 10, 2 );
```

(The Custom Post Type has a registered name of `directory`) - it doesn't add it to the action row underneath the entry title. When I do it for the posts or pages, like this:

```
add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'rd_duplicate_post_link', 10, 2 );
```

it works perfectly. I've been reading that `post_row_actions` has been deprecated but I can't find anywhere that says it's replacement. Does anyone know how to get this working for my Custom Post Type?

Comment: Please add all relevant code to your question.

Comment: it's on the link I posted on the first line (http://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/duplicate-post.html), but it's quite long so I thought it best to leave it there. I can add it in if you want though?

Comment: You might want to strip it down to the necessary parts, but generally outgoing link sources can vanish and than there is no information available and the question in the future more or less useless.

Comment: ok I'll do that, your explanation makes sense, thanks @ialocin :)

Comment: Looking at the source for "wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php", it calls `page_row_actions` for hierarchical post types, and `post_row_actions` for all others (there's no post_type-specific filter), so one of them should work for you. (You'll have to check the passed in `$post->post_type` for varying behaviour.) Nothing in the code anyway about deprecation.

Answer (score 13):

As @bonger commented, there is no custom post type filter despite what you've read.

To use this filter for a specific post type, the best way is to use the `post_row_actions` filter and then test against the passed in `$post->post_type`.

I've used the code below to add links to the actions row for a specific post type (in this case, myposttype).

This will need to be edited to work for your own post type, and obviously for the new link to actually do anything more code is needed, but this is the idea:

```
function my_duplicate_post_link($actions, $post)
{
    if ($post->post_type=='myposttype')
    {
        $actions['duplicate'] = '<a href="#" title="" rel="permalink">Duplicate</a>';
    }
    return $actions;
}
add_filter('post_row_actions', 'my_duplicate_post_link', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Also, your Custom Post Type must be non-hierarchical. 
`'hierarchical' => false` when declaring your CPT with`register_post_type('MyCustomPostType'...)` 
[Check WP Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_row_actions)

Answer (score -1):

```
//Post, page or all register custom post types

function im_duplicate_post_link($actions, $post)
{
    // get all post type which is register
    $posttypes = get_post_types(array('public' => true), 'names', 'and');
    foreach ($posttypes as $post_type)
    {
        $posttype[] = $post_type;
    }
    //check current post type is in "$posttype"  array, if it's in array then display duplicate link.
    if (in_array($post->post_type, $posttype))
    {
        $actions['duplicate'] = '<a href="admin.php?action=im_duplicate_post_as_draft&amp;post=' . $post->ID . '" title="Duplicate this item" rel="permalink">Duplicate</a>';
    }
    return $actions;
}
// this hook for post and custom post type
add_filter('post_row_actions', 'im_duplicate_post_link', 10, 2);
// this hook for page
add_filter('page_row_actions', 'im_duplicate_post_link', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Please, explain how your code works and why it answers the question. Only code is not a good answer.

Comment: In above code used for duplicate post,page or any custom post type.